# UITextField Custom Input View won't dismiss

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I am having some issues with a custom input view for my UITextField, i have used a UIDatePickerView with an Accessory view which is a UIButton. I have hooked the unbutton up to a method which captures the value, loads it into the field and then attempts to dismiss custom input view without any success...

My Field declaration and initialisation looks as follows

```
    int width = self.controller.view.frame.size.width;
UITextField* field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((width / 100) * 40, 5, (width / 100) * 60, 40)];
self.fieldControl = field;
field.placeholder = @"Select Date..";
field.textColor = self.controller.fieldColor;
self.datePicker = [UIDatePicker new];
field.delegate = self;
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
UIButton* close = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[close setFrame:CGRectMake(width - 60, 20, 50, 50)];
close.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;
[close setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[close addTarget:self action:@selector(datePicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
field.inputAccessoryView = close;
field.inputView = self.datePicker;
[self addSubview:field];
```

My Date picked method looks like this

```
    -(void)datePicked
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];


    UITextView* field = self.fieldControl;
    field.text = stringFromDate;

    [field endEditing:YES];
    [field resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I can't figure out why this is not working, i have tried the endEditing method on various views and nothing seems to work. I notice that the text field does lose voce in that it no longer shows the flashing curser... tapping on another uitextfield shows the regular keyboard which when dismissed closes my custom input view... what am i missing?

Comment: datePicked method is exactly invoked?

Comment: sorry i don't think i understand? the method is called, the text field is updated but the input view does not hide.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to assign the properties to your UITextField directly on the instance variable, rather than setting them to a new UITextField and setting that text field to your instance property as you are currently doing.

Or make the fieldControl property "assign" rather than "strong", so its not retained (which may be causing it to lose its reference when you attempt to resign it.

like this:

@property (nonatomic, assign) UITextField *fieldControl;

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i have changed the field property to assign rather than strong and i now assign directly to the property rather than creating a local, the end of my DatePicked is shown below but i am still having the same issue.

    ((UITextField*)self.fieldControl).text = value;
    [((UITextField*)self.fieldControl) endEditing:YES];
    [((UITextField*)self.fieldControl) resignFirstResponder];

Comment: I'm not sure, I tested your exact code and it actually works for me.  Perhaps you can provide the complete code for your ViewController class? And are you using a nib file?

Comment: hmm, i could but there is lots of it... Can you share the code you used to reproduce it so i can see how it differs from mine? One difference i suspect is my that my fieldControl property is of type id which i can't see making a difference.. Also the code i shared is from inside a UITableViewCell which is being added via a controller to a TableView. Would this have any bearing? I appreciate your help so far!! :D

Comment: Its probably something to do with the UITableViewCell and knowing how to properly add controls to it, as well as how to properly respond to events that occur when interacting with those controls.  I recommend to read more under Listing 5-7 on Apple's UITableViewCell Reference - https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1